# Limiting agRichSelectCellEditor to n-items?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way to restrict the height (eg to n * .cellHeight) for the built-in agRichSelectCellEditor?

I see there is a cellRenderer but this only affects the individual list-items - I know I can always implement a custom editor but wanted to see if this was possible first

Comment: can you elaborate more on *restrict the height (eg to n-number of list items)*?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi so if the individual cellHeight (this is configurable) is 40px, then the total height of the dropdown should be n * cellHeight pixels

Answer (score 1):

override the CSS rule `.ag-rich-select-list`

```
.ag-rich-select-list {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```js
var students = [{
  first_name: 'Bob',
  last_name: 'Harrison',
  gender: 'Male',
  address: '1197 Thunder Wagon Common, Cataract, RI, 02987-1016, US, (401) 747-0763',
  mood: "Happy",
  country: {
    name: 'Ireland',
    code: 'IE'
  }
}, {
  first_name: 'Mary',
  last_name: 'Wilson',
  gender: 'Female',
  age: 11,
  address: '3685 Rocky Glade, Showtucket, NU, X1E-9I0, CA, (867) 371-4215',
  mood: "Sad",
  country: {
    name: 'Ireland',
    code: 'IE'
  }
}, {
  first_name: 'Sadiq',
  last_name: 'Khan',
  gender: 'Male',
  age: 12,
  address: '3235 High Forest, Glen Campbell, MS, 39035-6845, US, (601) 638-8186',
  mood: "Happy",
  country: {
    name: 'Ireland',
    code: 'IE'
  }
}, {
  first_name: 'Jerry',
  last_name: 'Mane',
  gender: 'Male',
  age: 12,
  address: '2234 Sleepy Pony Mall , Drain, DC, 20078-4243, US, (202) 948-3634',
  mood: "Happy",
  country: {
    name: 'Ireland',
    code: 'IE'
  }
}];

// double the array twice, make more data!
students.forEach(function(item) {
  students.push(cloneObject(item));
});
students.forEach(function(item) {
  students.push(cloneObject(item));
});
students.forEach(function(item) {
  students.push(cloneObject(item));
});

function cloneObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var columnDefs = [{
    field: "first_name",
    headerName: "First Name",
    width: 120,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "last_name",
    headerName: "Last Name",
    width: 120,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "gender",
    width: 100,
    editable: true,
    cellRenderer: 'genderCellRenderer',
    cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      cellRenderer: 'genderCellRenderer',
      values: ['Male', 'Female']
    }
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    width: 80,
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor'
  },
  {
    field: "mood",
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: 'moodCellRenderer',
    cellEditor: 'moodEditor',
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "country",
    width: 110,
    cellRenderer: 'countryCellRenderer',
    cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    keyCreator: function(country) {
      return country.name;
    },
    cellEditorParams: {
      cellRenderer: 'countryCellRenderer',
      values: [{
          name: 'Ireland',
          code: 'IE'
        },
        {
          name: 'UK',
          code: 'UK'
        },
        {
          name: 'France',
          code: 'FR'
        }
      ]
    },
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "address",
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      maxLength: '300', // override the editor defaults
      cols: '50',
      rows: '6'
    }
  }
];

var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: students,
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    filter: true,
    resizable: true
  },
  onRowEditingStarted: function(event) {
    console.log('never called - not doing row editing');
  },
  onRowEditingStopped: function(event) {
    console.log('never called - not doing row editing');
  },
  onCellEditingStarted: function(event) {
    console.log('cellEditingStarted');
  },
  onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
    console.log('cellEditingStopped');
  },
  components: {
    genderCellRenderer: GenderCellRenderer,
    numericCellEditor: NumericCellEditor,
    moodCellRenderer: MoodCellRenderer,
    moodEditor: MoodEditor,
    countryCellRenderer: CountryCellRenderer
  }
};

function getCharCodeFromEvent(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  return (typeof event.which == "undefined") ? event.keyCode : event.which;
}

function isCharNumeric(charStr) {
  return !!/\d/.test(charStr);
}

function isKeyPressedNumeric(event) {
  var charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  return isCharNumeric(charStr);
}

// simple function cellRenderer, just returns back the name of the country
function CountryCellRenderer(params) {
  return params.value.name;
}

// function to act as a class
function NumericCellEditor() {}

// gets called once before the renderer is used
NumericCellEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
  // create the cell
  this.eInput = document.createElement('input');

  if (isCharNumeric(params.charPress)) {
    this.eInput.value = params.charPress;
  } else {
    if (params.value !== undefined && params.value !== null) {
      this.eInput.value = params.value;
    }
  }

  var that = this;
  this.eInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (!isKeyPressedNumeric(event)) {
      that.eInput.focus();
      if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    } else if (that.isKeyPressedNavigation(event)) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });

  // only start edit if key pressed is a number, not a letter
  var charPressIsNotANumber = params.charPress && ('1234567890'.indexOf(params.charPress) < 0);
  this.cancelBeforeStart = charPressIsNotANumber;
};

NumericCellEditor.prototype.isKeyPressedNavigation = function(event) {
  return event.keyCode === 39 ||
    event.keyCode === 37;
};


// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eInput;
};

// focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
NumericCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
  this.eInput.focus();
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelBeforeStart = function() {
  return this.cancelBeforeStart;
};

// example - will reject the number if it contains the value 007
// - not very practical, but demonstrates the method.
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelAfterEnd = function() {
  var value = this.getValue();
  return value.indexOf('007') >= 0;
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
  return this.eInput.value;
};

// any cleanup we need to be done here
NumericCellEditor.prototype.destroy = function() {
  // but this example is simple, no cleanup, we could  even leave this method out as it's optional
};

// if true, then this editor will appear in a popup 
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function() {
  // and we could leave this method out also, false is the default
  return false;
};


function GenderCellRenderer() {}

GenderCellRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
  if (params.value !== "" || params.value !== undefined || params.value !== null) {
    var gender = '<img border="0" width="15" height="10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/' + params.value.toLowerCase() + '.png">';
    this.eGui.innerHTML = gender + ' ' + params.value;
  }
};

GenderCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eGui;
};

function MoodCellRenderer() {}

MoodCellRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
  if (params.value !== "" || params.value !== undefined || params.value !== null) {
    var imgForMood = params.value === 'Happy' ? 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley.png' : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley-sad.png';
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '<img width="20px" src="' + imgForMood + '" />';
  }
};

MoodCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.eGui;
};

function MoodEditor() {
  this.defaultImgStyle = 'padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;  border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 4px;';
  this.selectedImgStyle = 'padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid lightgreen; padding: 4px;';
}

MoodEditor.prototype.onKeyDown = function(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == 37 || // left
    key == 39) { // right
    this.toggleMood();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

MoodEditor.prototype.toggleMood = function() {
  this.selectMood(this.mood === 'Happy' ? 'Sad' : 'Happy');
};

MoodEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.container = document.createElement('div');
  this.container.style = "border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid grey;background: #e6e6e6;padding: 15px; text-align:center;display:inline-block;outline:none";
  this.container.tabIndex = "0"; // to allow the div to capture keypresses

  this.happyImg = document.createElement('img');
  this.happyImg.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley.png';
  this.happyImg.style = this.defaultImgStyle;

  this.sadImg = document.createElement('img');
  this.sadImg.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley-sad.png';
  this.sadImg.style = this.defaultImgStyle;

  this.container.appendChild(this.happyImg);
  this.container.appendChild(this.sadImg);

  var that = this;
  this.happyImg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    that.selectMood('Happy');
    params.stopEditing();
  });
  this.sadImg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    that.selectMood('Sad');
    params.stopEditing();
  });
  this.container.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    that.onKeyDown(event)
  });

  this.selectMood(params.value);
};

MoodEditor.prototype.selectMood = function(mood) {
  this.mood = mood;
  this.happyImg.style = (mood === 'Happy') ? this.selectedImgStyle : this.defaultImgStyle;
  this.sadImg.style = (mood === 'Sad') ? this.selectedImgStyle : this.defaultImgStyle;
};

// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
MoodEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
  return this.container;
};

MoodEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
  this.container.focus();
};

MoodEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
  return this.mood;
};

// any cleanup we need to be done here
MoodEditor.prototype.destroy = function() {};

MoodEditor.prototype.isPopup = function() {
  return true;
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

```css
.ag-rich-select-list {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    var __basePath = './';
  </script>
  <style media="only screen">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    html {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 1rem;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@24.1.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-alpine"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks good but one problem: in my app if I fill up the entire grid with rows and trigger an edit from the last row, the drop down will push space down from the bottom of the grid and the last row this seems to be caused by height: auto

Comment: Looks like ag-grid dynamically adds inline style to calculate the top / bottom of the grid when triggering the dropdown open (eg <div class="ag-popup-editor ag-ltr ag-popup-child" tabindex="-1" style="min-width: 202px; left: 362px; top: 556px;">) ..setting height: auto seems to break this injection logic

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with AG-Grid that would be addressed by AG-3332 in https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/